# Standard for publication-ready R-based geographic images?

Tags: r, ggmap, leaflet-r

I've been using the `ggmap` package to create figures that will go in journal articles for many years. These maps are a little harder to create than Leaflet maps, and as OpenStreetMap and Google have both shut down their tile APIs, getting background tiles that work for me has become more difficult. (Stamen is okay, but the selections don't always work).

I've seen ways to export leaflet maps as static images, but these often leave artifacts like zoom buttons that I definitely don't want in my paper. What is the best tool now (2019) for creating clean, publication-quality geographic images in R?

As a further complication, I usually write my articles in `rmarkdown` so that my figures can update with changes to the data, research, etc. Taking a screenshot of a leaflet map where I just crop out the things I don't want isn't ideal.

Comment: which OSM tile api is shutdown? Have google really shut theirs down or have they locked it down with an API key? Have you tried `tmap`?

Comment: Google has locked it with an API key. OpenStreetMap has locked its API from exporting in the way ggmap works, according to [this issue](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/117)

Comment: I just learned about `tmap` in my searching that prompted this question. I guess I want to make sure that I'm not missing anything else before I learn a new syntax.

Comment: `tmap` does not support basemaps in the non-interactive view, so I'm in basically the same boat as I was in with `leaflet`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use basemaps in the non-interactive mode of the **tmap** package.
However, it requires two steps:

1. Downloading/preparing raster data with three layers (RGB)
2. Start making the map with `tm_shape(my_rgb_data) + tm_rgb()`

You can see some examples of using this approach at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56972352/2602477.